# Sending Channel Uri to cloud service

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, push-notification

I was developing an app to receive push notifications.By using below code I had obtained channel uri..Now my problem is how should I send this to webservice I am using..

```
    public MainPage()
        {

           HttpNotificationChannel pushChannel;

        // The name of our push channel.
        string channelName = "ToastSampleChannel";

        InitializeComponent();

        // Try to find the push channel.
        pushChannel = HttpNotificationChannel.Find(channelName);

        // If the channel was not found, then create a new connection to the push service.
        if (pushChannel == null)
        {
            pushChannel = new HttpNotificationChannel(channelName);

            // Register for all the events before attempting to open the channel.
            pushChannel.ChannelUriUpdated += new EventHandler<NotificationChannelUriEventArgs>(PushChannel_ChannelUriUpdated);
            pushChannel.ErrorOccurred += new EventHandler<NotificationChannelErrorEventArgs>(PushChannel_ErrorOccurred);

            // Register for this notification only if you need to receive the notifications while your application is running.
            pushChannel.ShellToastNotificationReceived += new EventHandler<NotificationEventArgs>(PushChannel_ShellToastNotificationReceived);

            pushChannel.Open();

            // Bind this new channel for toast events.
            pushChannel.BindToShellToast();

        }
        else
        {
            // The channel was already open, so just register for all the events.
            pushChannel.ChannelUriUpdated += new EventHandler<NotificationChannelUriEventArgs>(PushChannel_ChannelUriUpdated);
            pushChannel.ErrorOccurred += new EventHandler<NotificationChannelErrorEventArgs>(PushChannel_ErrorOccurred);

            // Register for this notification only if you need to receive the notifications while your application is running.
            pushChannel.ShellToastNotificationReceived += new EventHandler<NotificationEventArgs>(PushChannel_ShellToastNotificationReceived);
            // Display the URI for testing purposes. Normally, the URI would be passed back to your web service at this point.
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(pushChannel.ChannelUri.ToString());
            MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Channel Uri is {0}",
                        pushChannel.ChannelUri.ToString()));


        }
    }



    /// <summary>
    /// Event handler for when the push channel Uri is updated.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    void PushChannel_ChannelUriUpdated(object sender, NotificationChannelUriEventArgs e)
    {

        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
        {
            // Display the new URI for testing purposes.   Normally, the URI would be passed back to your web service at this point.
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e.ChannelUri.ToString());
            MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Channel Uri is {0}",
                e.ChannelUri.ToString()));

        });
    }

   void PushChannel_ErrorOccurred(object sender, NotificationChannelErrorEventArgs e)
    {
        // Error handling logic for your particular application would be here.
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
            MessageBox.Show(String.Format("A push notification {0} error occurred.  {1} ({2}) {3}",
                e.ErrorType, e.Message, e.ErrorCode, e.ErrorAdditionalData))
                );
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Event handler for when a toast notification arrives while your application is running.  
    /// The toast will not display if your application is running so you must add this
    /// event handler if you want to do something with the toast notification.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sender"></param>
    /// <param name="e"></param>
    void PushChannel_ShellToastNotificationReceived(object sender, NotificationEventArgs e)
    {
        StringBuilder message = new StringBuilder();
        string relativeUri = string.Empty;

        message.AppendFormat("Received Toast {0}:\n", DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString());

        // Parse out the information that was part of the message.
        foreach (string key in e.Collection.Keys)
        {
            message.AppendFormat("{0}: {1}\n", key, e.Collection[key]);

            if (string.Compare(
                key,
                "wp:Param",
                System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                System.Globalization.CompareOptions.IgnoreCase) == 0)
            {
                relativeUri = e.Collection[key];
            }
        }

        // Display a dialog of all the fields in the toast.
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => MessageBox.Show(message.ToString()));

    }
```

And after receiving Channel uri How should I pass it to webserver.I had used below code but not working.

```
private void RegisterUriWithService()
        {
          string baseUri = "http://localhost:8000/RegirstatorService/Register?uri={0}"; 

       string theUri = String.Format(baseUri, pushChannel.ChannelUri.ToString());
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(theUri);
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        client.DownloadStringCompleted += (s, e) =>
        {
            if (null == e.Error)
                Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => UpdateStatus("Registration succeeded"));
            else
                Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
                                UpdateStatus("Registration failed: " + e.Error.Message));
        };
        client.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(theUri));
    }
```

Errors were raising like

Error:Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'System.Delegate' because it is not a delegate type.
Error:The name 'pushChannel' does not exist in the current context.

Control is not going inside RegisterUriWithService() function.How can I overcome this errors and send channel uri to webservice.
Anybody please help me..
ManyThanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

RegisterUriWithService() is not called from anywhere in your code.

Rewrite your method like this

> ```
>     private void RegisterUriWithService(string pushChannelUri)
>     {
>       string baseUri = "http://localhost:8000/RegirstatorService/Register?uri={0}"; 
>
>    string theUri = String.Format(baseUri, pushChannelUri); // pushChannelUri is passed as parameter to this method
>     System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(theUri);
>     WebClient client = new WebClient();
>     client.DownloadStringCompleted += (s, e) =>
>     {
>         if (null == e.Error)
>             Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => UpdateStatus("Registration succeeded"));
>         else
>             Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
>                             UpdateStatus("Registration failed: " + e.Error.Message));
>     };
>     client.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(theUri));
>     }
> ```

When your push channel is opened and Channel URI got updated, PushChannel_ChannelUriUpdated event will be fired.

Store the push channel URI in a local variable **pushChannelUri** and **CALL THE METHOD** RegisterUriWithService(pushChannelUri) from there.

If the push channel already exists with an URI then control goes to else block

> ```
>        else    
>        {
>         // The channel was already open, so just register for all the events.
>         pushChannel.ChannelUriUpdated += new EventHandler<NotificationChannelUriEventArgs>(PushChannel_ChannelUriUpdated);
>         pushChannel.ErrorOccurred += new EventHandler<NotificationChannelErrorEventArgs>(PushChannel_ErrorOccurred);
>
>         // Register for this notification only if you need to receive the notifications while your application is running.
>         pushChannel.ShellToastNotificationReceived += new EventHandler<NotificationEventArgs>(PushChannel_ShellToastNotificationReceived);
>         // Display the URI for testing purposes. Normally, the URI would be passed back to your web service at this point.
>         System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(pushChannel.ChannelUri.ToString());
>         MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Channel Uri is {0}",
>                     pushChannel.ChannelUri.ToString()));
>
>        pushChannelUri = pushChannel.ChannelUri.ToString();
>        }
> ```

**CALL THE METHOD** RegisterUriWithService(pushChannelUri) from this block.

Comment: Ya I have done the same process..Called RegisterUriWithService from else block.And It worked fine for me...Thank you...